# why is there a "new" keyword before PolyLineOptions()?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I checked the source code and it wasn't too clear, I thought `new` was only used to instantiate objects?

```
mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(startCoords, finalCoords))
```

Comment: I don't know about this specific Java topic, but usually an "options object" is used and passed to some method instead of several parameters separated by commas. An "option builder" like that one is easier to manage and encompass all the necessary data.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought new was only used to instantiate objects?

Correct. And here you are creating a new `PolylineOptions` instance.

Answer (score 1):

> In short: this is a **[syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)**

When executing  `new PolylineOptions().add(startCoords, finalCoords)` you actually execute 2 commands at once and its equivalent to:

1. `PolylineOptions tmp = new PolylineOptions();`
2. `tmp.add(startCoords, finalCoords);`

And only after executing the second line you pass a reference of `tmp` to `mMap.addPolyline(...)`.